# Alternatives to 'Docker Compose's integration for ECS and ACI will be retired in November 2023'

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

We are currently using 'docker compose' to deploy our applications on ECS, and during its usage, we have noticed the following notice:

'Docker Compose's integration for ECS and ACI will be retired in November 2023.'

Is there an alternative that allows us to reuse the compose.yaml files we have? I tried using 'ecs-composex,' but it is giving me problems.

EDIT: We use Windows.